# How do you map a relationship by a primary key in Restkit?

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

Haven't been able to find an up to date example on how to map a relationship like the one below.

```
{
    "seats": [
        {
            "number": "2A",
            "user_id": 1
        },
        {
            "number": "4E",
            "user_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

using RestKit (0.9.3) to a model of

```
User
NSUInteger id
NSString* name

Seat
NSString* number
User* user;
```

Comment: No Coredata, just RKObjectMapping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe RestKit can do exactly what you want out of the box.

Your best bet might be to modify your data to be more RestKit friendly. You could do this via the objectLoader:willMapData: delegate method:

http://restkit.org/api/0.9.3/Protocols/RKObjectLoaderDelegate.html#//api/name/objectLoader:willMapData: